# Riak 2.0 Java client returns empty collection on Map-Reduce

Tags: riak

I've been trying to get a simple map-reduce working all day.  While I'd like to make a map-reduce which does a batch roll-up of keys using a key-filter, for no all I'm trying to do is get MR to return the values in a particular bucket.

Here's my code (scala using the 2.0 riak java client):

```
import com.basho.riak.client.api.commands.mapreduce.BucketMapReduce
import com.basho.riak.client.core.query.functions.{Function => RiakFunction}
new BucketMapReduce.Builder().withNamespace(ns).
  withMapPhase(RiakFunction.newAnonymousJsFunction("""function(v) { return [v]; }""")).
  build()
```

I've also tried:

```
import com.basho.riak.client.api.commands.mapreduce.BucketMapReduce
import com.basho.riak.client.core.query.functions.{Function => RiakFunction}
new BucketMapReduce.Builder().withNamespace(ns).
  withMapPhase(RiakFunction.newErlangFunction("riak_kv_mapreduce", "map_identity")).
  build()
```

Both of these return empty-arrays when I hit my riak server.   Anything I'm missing that would cause this to happen?  I see no error output whatsoever in the logs (which is actually been par for the course when errors occur in the Java client).

Comment: I'm not especially familiar with scala so perhaps I'm misreading, but I don't see where you've specified the inputs to the map reduce job.

Comment: What inputs do you mean?  The only things I see in the builder are:

withNamespace, withMapPhase, withReducePhase, withKeyFilter